# Form appearing again after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to implement a search mechanism for my website using AJAX. The search mechanism is working fine. But there is one problem. The form is appearing again after my ajax request. Something like below.[image]

I'm posting few lines of code that are necessary. Please have a look.

```
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
function searchMyWebsite()
{
    var s = _("searchquery").value;
    var f = _("filter1").value;
    if(s == "")
    {
        alert("Please type something into the search box");
    }
    else if(s.length < 3)
    {
        alert("Please enter atleast 3 characters to search");
    }
    else
    {
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "search2.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) 
            {
                if(ajax.responseText != "failed")
                {
                    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
                else
                {
                    _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("search="+s+"&filter="+f);    
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search_form" id="search_form" onSubmit="return false;">
  Search: <input name="searchquery" id="searchquery" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100">
  <button id="searchBtn" onClick="searchMyWebsite()">Search</button>
  <br /><br />
  Search In:
  <select name="filter1" id="filter1">
  <option value="users">Users</option>
  <option value="forum">Forums</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div><span id="status"></span></div>
</body>
```

Why is this happening when the ajax request is working fine? If my php code has to be referred to provide a solution, Then plzz inform me and I will update the qn.

Comment: check search2.php looks like it has some html content which is getting returned on success.

Comment: I see that this is happening on search2.php. Are both the files (one with ajax code and the other called by ajax) the same?

Comment: I am not sure but try to use  onSubmit="javascript:return false;" instead of  onSubmit="return false;"

Comment: @Gopal1216 You cannot have AJAX calling the same file. This is why your HTML code is being returned. Put the PHP code which is required during AJAX into a new file and call that file in your AJAX method. Or maybe you can tweak your PHP code a little so as to not display the HTML, paste your PHP here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to exit the script by using the `exit();`whereever necessary.

I myself am answering the question because this might be useful to someone.

Since I'm not exiting the script the form is getting posted again on the page. Now i'm exiting the script and everything is working fine.